# Grouping variables select first row (keep one column), last row (keep different column)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have the following table:

```
id  origin destination price
 1     A      B          2
 1     C      D          2
 2     A      B          3
 3     B      E          6
 3     E      C          6
 3     C      F          6
```

Basically what I want to do is to group it by `id`, select the first element from `origin`, and keep the last element from `destination` resulting in this table.

```
id  origin destination price
 1     A      D          2
 2     A      B          3
 3     B      F          6
```

I know how to select the first and last row, but not to do what I want.

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
slice(c(1, n())) %>%
ungroup()
```

Is it possible to do this with `dplyr` or even with `data.table`?

Comment: Just do `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(origin = first(origin), destination = last(destination), price = first(price))`

Comment: @akrun Works perfectly as always. Didn't know about the first and last functions on summarise. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `library(data.table)`:

```
unique(setDT(df)[, "origin" := origin[1] , by = id][, "destination" := destination[.N], by = id][, "price" := price[1] , by = id][])
```

A shortcut suggested by Imo:

```
setDT(df)[, .(origin=origin[1], destination=destination[.N], price=price[1]), by=id]
```

Comment: In one call, `dt[, .(origin=origin[1], destination=destination[.N], price=price[1]), by=id]`.

Comment: nice, feel free to post, then i delete this one.

Comment: That's OK. You can add it to your answer if you want.

Comment: The shortcut works perfectly. Small detail that the data frame has to be converted first to data.table.

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `split`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), 
                      function(a) with(a, data.frame(origin=head(origin,1), destination=tail(destination,1), price=head(price,1)))))

#  origin destination price
#1      A           D     2
#2      A           B     3
#3      B           F     6
```